# When windows service is installed under different user it requires manual "Log On" is this expected?

Tags: windows, login, services, windows-services, golang

using golang [example](https://github.com/golang/sys/tree/master/windows/svc/example) I created windows service application, as mentioned in documentation I configured with service user and password. I'm using a batch script that will execute

```
    @REM install windows service using that application.
    app install
    timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL

    @REM start service using sc.exe command.
    sc.exe start testapp
```

it works fine with "Administrator" account.

But if the same service is installed under "test" user which had admin rights it, it won't star the service. I need to do manual log on from "services.msc" then it works, username and password are correct.

[manual log on message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoLiq.jpg)

Is there any way I can do this log on in batch script? or this is expected behavior ?

Note that during "install" operation service username and password are configured with this "test" user. And "test" has "Log on as a service" rights based on [this](https://winshuttle-help.s3.amazonaws.com/foundation/en/assigning-user-account-login-as-service.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If windows service need to be installed under different user. That user should have "Log on as a service" permission. Without that service won;t start. Check this [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scsm/enable-service-log-on-sm?view=sc-sm-2019#enable-service-log-on-through-a-local-group-policy)

There are lot of powershell scripts there to do this. Incase this need to be enabled using batch or something.

In my case, that another user should have admin right , as well as "log on as a service" permission , after adding this permissions it works fine for me.